# Need help in regex pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

i have this Regex pattern

```
\=[a-zA-Z\.\:\[\]_\(\)\&\$\%#\-\@\!0-9;=\?/\+\xBF\~]+[?\s+|?>]
```

and i have this HTML

```
1.<a href="mailto: abc@xyz.com?subject=Long Term Care Enrollment">esc@xyz.com</a>
2.<a href="mailto: abc@xyz.com?subject=LongTerm Care Enrollment">johnross@zys.com</a>
3.<a href="mailto: abc@xyz.com?subject=LongTermCareEnrollment">johnross@wen.com</a>
```

Here the problem is, 
I need to avoid first and second as it has white space as well and it is valid attributes.
But only the third one is working as it does't has white spaces. 
means nothing should be selected with the above pattern.

here is direct link to test

```
http://regexr.com?31r61
```

Please help!
Thanks,

Comment: I didn't understand what you want. You need a pattern to match these three href values?

Comment: Real email addresses in the regexr link?

Comment: could you read the href attributes into an array and check that there is only one space, located immediately after the `mailto:`?

Comment: I need only those attribute values which has no double/single quotes, i need to put double quotes around the attribute values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**
If you just want to match unquoted attributes, this should work:

```
[<\s]+[\w]+(=[^\"][^\s>]*)
```

Kind of inelegant but let me know if that does what you want.

---

Which pattern are you trying to match? All three? And if so, which portion? The subject or the email? If you're just trying to match the subject, try using this as the pattern to match:

```
\=\"mailto:[^?]*\?subject=([^\"]*)\"\>
```

That will return a match where the group is the subject itself.

Comment: I need only those attribute values which has no double/single quotes, i need to put double quotes around the attribute values

Comment: So in your above examples, what are you trying to match exactly?

Comment: all attributes which doesn't have doubles quotes, that pattern is working fine with following html
<a href=mailto:abc@xyz.com?subject=LongTermCareEnrollment>johnross@wen.com</a>

but not with
<a href="mailto: abc@xyz.com?subject=LongTerm Care Enrollment">johnross@wen.com</a>
in second case, nothing should be matched because href value already has double quotes, but in pattern gives me 
=LongTerm in selection

Comment: still not correct...

i just need to match "=second" from the following html


<a firstattr="first first" secondattr=second thirdattr="third third">test</a>

Comment: Okay, see my adjustment. You need to reference the group in this case - are you familiar with that process? Referencing the matched group will return `=second` in your example.

Answer (score 0):

That is a wicked character class....

why don't you try something a bit more reasonable. Try this...

```
\=".*?(?<!\\)"
```

that will match anything in the parenthesis after href if that's what you're trying to get. If you're looking for more than that, this regex can easily by modified.

Comment: I need only those attribute values which has no double/single quotes, i need to put double quotes around the attribute values